# GraphQL response array getting empty out of nowhere right before return(??)

Tags: graphql, typeorm

So I'm trying to build a resolver for graphQL which is supposed to return an array of objects. The values for these objects come from a series of TypeORM selecting operations. And when I tried asking for a response in the graphql playground I only got empty arrays, so I started debugging the resolver using console.logs, but the thing is, inside the forEach loops I use the code seems to have the desired result: an array with objects in it. But when I log the same array right before returning it is empty:

```js
  @Query(() => [response])
  async getTeacherFromSubjectName(
    @Arg("subjectName") subjectName: string, 
  ): Promise<response[] | undefined> {
    const subject = await Subject.findOne({name: subjectName}); 
    const subjectId = subject?.id; 
    let responseArray: response[] = []; 

    const qb = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select("teacher")
      .from(Teacher, "teacher")
      .where(`teacher.subjectId = ${subjectId}`)
      .getMany()

    qb.forEach(async (teacher) => {
     const qb = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select("lectureTime")
      .from(LectureTime, "lectureTime")
      .where(`lectureTime.teacherId = ${teacher.id}`)
      .getMany()

      responseArray.push( {
        teacher: teacher.name, 
        lectures: qb, 
      } ); 
      console.log(responseArray) // [{ teacher: 'Dirceu', lectures: [ [LectureTime] ] }, { teacher: 
                                     'Patrícia', lectures: [ [LectureTime], [LectureTime] ] } ]
    })
    

    console.log(responseArray) // []
    return responseArray; 

  }
```

What I get on the console is the following:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHGx1.jpg)

I actually have no idea of what is going on here, you can see in the image that the order of the logs is inverted (log right before return is circled in blue).

I am certain that it is a silly problem and if you guys could point it out for me I would be very thankful.

Comment: hmmm,  `await qb.forEach(` ? probably you should use `Promise.all`

Comment: yeah, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As xadm said on the comments, you are not awaiting for the promises you are creating inside forEach. In that case you need to map to the promises, so you'll have an array of the Promises and them await them all.

```js
     // Changed to map so you get the return values
     const promises = qb.map(async (teacher) => {
     const qb = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select("lectureTime")
      .from(LectureTime, "lectureTime")
      .where(`lectureTime.teacherId = ${teacher.id}`)
      .getMany()

      responseArray.push( {
        teacher: teacher.name, 
        lectures: qb, 
      } ); 
      console.log(responseArray);
    });

    // Await for all the promises to be completed, regardless of order.
    await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: thank you very much, that solved it! really appreciate it.